# misunderstood Javascript functions call

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I trying to customize `HTML file input` and wrote simplest jquery API function:

```
(function($)
{    
  $.fn.selectFileInputGUI = function()
  { 
    var outerWrapper = $('<div>').css({'display':'inline-block'});
    var innerWrapper = $('<div>').css({'width':'0', 'height':'0', 'overflow':'hidden'});
    var fileInput    = $('<input>').attr({type:'file'});
    var fileNameHTML = $('<div>').css({'display':'inline-block', 'margin-left':'3px'});

    var selectBtnGUI = $('<button>').addClass('btn btn-success btn-sm').text('Select file').click(function()
       {
          $.fn.selectFileInputGUI.resetInput();
          fileInput.trigger('click');
       });

       fileInput.on('change', function()
       {   
          $.fn.selectFileInputGUI.displayFileName();
       });

    $(this)
    .append(outerWrapper.append(innerWrapper.append(fileInput)).append(selectBtnGUI))
    .append(fileNameHTML);

   $.fn.selectFileInputGUI.displayFileName = function()
   {
      var fileName = fileInput.val();
      if(fileName.length > 0)
      {
          var pos = fileName.lastIndexOf("\\");
          if(pos != -1) fileName = fileName.substr(pos + 1);
          if(fileName.length > 14) fileName = fileName.substr(0, 14) + '...';
       } else
       {
          fileName = 'File not selected';
       }
       fileNameHTML.text(fileName);
};


   $.fn.selectFileInputGUI.resetInput = function()
   {           
     fileInput.wrap('<form>').parent('form').trigger('reset');
     fileInput.unwrap();
   };   
}
})(jQuery);
```

When I trying to apply `selectFileInputGUI` api function to the several selectors, only last selector handles well - http://jsfiddle.net/URKM5/5/

How to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is in how you reuse the variable `fileInput` and `fileNameHTML`, after user selecting the file, and you call this `$.fn.selectFileInputGUI.displayFileName();` the `fileInput` and `fileNameHTML` always refer to the `fileInput` and `fileNameHTML` of the second fileDialog (because the second fileDialog is initialized after the first and all these variables are overridden). So to solve this problem, you have to pass these variables via the so-called ***event data***, it's much helpful in this case:

```
//Note the second argument, it's passed in as event data
//You can access the event data via e.data
fileInput.on('change', fileNameHTML, function(e) {              
    $.fn.selectFileInputGUI.displayFileName($(this), e.data);
});
```

Your `displayFileName` need to accept 2 arguments, the first refers to the `fileInput` (which can be passed in as `$(this)` in the `onchange` event handler of the `fileInput`), the second refers to the `fileNameHTML` (which is passed in as `e.data`).

```
//note about the change of the arguments
$.fn.selectFileInputGUI.displayFileName = function(fileInput, fileNameHTML) {
   //the code is unchanged here ...
}
```

Now selecting the files between the 2 dialogs is independent.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/URKM5/9/)

After some deeper looking into the problem, looks like you don't need to use event data here. Just pass the `fileNameHTML` right as the second argument into `displayFileName(...)` function. **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/URKM5/11/)**